# How to create transporter for Protonmail in nodemailer.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I want to send email using nodemailer and the sender's email is of "Protonmail.com" domain. For this I created a transporter with host '127.0.0.1' and port 1025 but I am getting error. Am I doing anything wrong and is there any other approach to deal with this issue.

getting this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1025
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 1025,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Code of Transporter:

```
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 1025,
        secure: false, 
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL, 
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }, 
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }  
      });
```